# How send email with devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, initialization, sendgrid

I have the next problem, I want to send a email to recover the user's password with ResetMailer and devise's initializer but the email doesn't send.
This is my mailer:

```
class ResetMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'
  default from: 'my_email@gmail.com'
  def delivery_options
    {
      user_name:      'MyUserName',
      password:       '##########',
      domain:         'sendgrid.com/',
      address:        'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      port:           '25',
      authentication: :plain,
      enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
  end
end
```

I have this in my devise's initializer:

```
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
  # with default "from" parameter.
  # config.mailer_sender = 'desarrollocafeina@gmail.com'

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = 'ResetMailer'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow steps as bellow:

First, devise have a function that is [send_reset_password_instructions](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FRecoverable%2FClassMethods:send_reset_password_instructions), you can use it as: `current_user.send_reset_password_instructions`

Second, you should move mail setting in to `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port: 25,
  domain: '*',
  user_name: '*',
  password: '*',
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
}
```

Last, you can custom email reset password in `mailers` folder as:

```
class ResetMailer < Devise::Mailer
  default from: 'my_email@gmail.com'

  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: But I want to use dynamic delivery options